# Error 10054 "An Existing Connection Was Forcibly Closed by the Remote Host" on my machine only?

Tags: python, selenium, iedriverserver

I am trying to launch the Internet Explorer web browser using Python/Selenium. When I attempt to run the code, I receive the error as described above "urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))".

This error is only happening on my machine, my co-workers machine seem to be able to launch the code/browser just fine.

Read through various websites, attempted all solutions here: https://www.joecolantonio.com/selenium-webdriver-fix-for-3-common-ie-errors/.

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Ie()

driver.get('http://www.google.com')

The expected result should be the Internet Explorer web browser opening, and navigating to google.com.

The actual result is Error 10054: 
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. The "Solution" you provided is specific to Chrome. This is an issue with Internet Explorer. I have attempted to updated versions, to no avail. I have listed other solution steps that I have tried which do not work. The issue is specific to my machine and the code works just fine on my co workers machine.